# How to delay main thread until subthread is finished?

Tags: android, multithreading

Question is same with title. 
 How to do that?

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity {
    int threadCount = 0;
    int mainCount = 500;

    @override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        Thread t_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
                    threadCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        t_thread.start();

        // main thread.
        // how to delay a main thread until subthread is finished?
        mainCount += threadCount;

        // wanted result is 100500
        Log.i("MyTag", "" + mainCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't. Call whatever methods you need to at the end of the Thread.

Comment: It isn't recommended to delay the UI thread, because after 4-5 sec you'll get ANR and system will kill your app. Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Put `for loop` in the `doInBackground()` method, then get the result in `onPostExecute()` method that runs on UI thread.

Comment: and why would you want you thread to be blocked?

Comment: I'm trying that sub thread download image from url and display it in main_Activity. so mainActivity wait until url image downloading is finished.

Comment: If you don't want the user to interact with the UI until the image is displayed, put up a ProgressDialog, disable the Views, etc. If you block the main thread, you're going to get an ANR.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your advice.

Comment: You need to start thinking in an event-driven style.  Have the completion of the download trigger a UI change, but don't block the ui thread from being able to execute other critical methods while waiting for it, for example the user might change their mind and press the home button, something **you must promptly accept**.  If you still haven't returned from a previous method, onPause() can't be called, and this will cause an ANR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an interface:

```
public interface CountingListener{
    public void countingDone();
}
```

Then you'll need a reference to the main thread, so you can call it from your "counting" thread.

```
final Handler mainThread = new Handler();
```

This is the complete code:

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity {
int threadCount = 0;
int mainCount = 500;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    final Handler mainThread = new Handler();

    final CountingListener listener = new CountingListener() {
        @Override
        public void countingDone() {
            // main thread.
            // how to delay a main thread until subthread is finished?
            mainCount += threadCount;

            // wanted result is 100500
            Log.i("MyTag", "" + mainCount);

        }

    };

    Thread t_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                threadCount++;
            }

            mainThread.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listener.countingDone();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    t_thread.start();

}
```

This should work, without blocking your main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
try{
    t_thread.join();
} catch(InterruptedException e){
    // something useful
}
```

The Thread class doc is at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html

EDIT:
Just read the comments.  I agree with Mike. This is the way to do what you asked, but it isn't the way to solve your problem.